# Microsoft dynamics - GridControl.js error

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, lync

I have plug in CRM2011 to Outlook 2013, and when I try open CRM in Outlook I see this error

> Error: Could not complete the operation due to error 800a139e
>   Code: 0
>   URL; https://xx.xxx.xxx:123/_static/_gid/GridControl.js? ver=1594428341

You have an idea of ​​what could be the reason for the error?

Comment: do you have Outlook Client installed?

Comment: we had the issue and informed the microsoft about this bug. They are now working on it however I don't think it will be fixed soon.

Answer (score 1):

We had this issue on CRM 2013 and Outlook 2010. We tracked it back to the IM presence option.  If you go to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM menu, then Settings > Administration > System Setttings, you'll see an option titled "Set the IM presence option" under the general tab. Disable it and the error will disappear.